# Не отображаются некоторые блоки в IE9

Tags: php, wordpress, html5, css3, internet-explorer

Добрый день, есть сайт http://clients.concept1.co.il/broshline. Во всех браузерах кроме IE9 отображение нормальное, в IE9 некоторые блоки отсутствуют, в футере нет меню в хедере, на слайдере надписей. Как это исправить? 
В шапке стоят мета теги:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
<meta http-equiv=»X-UA-Compatible» content=»IE=EmulateIE9″>
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вы использовали Тег menu, который IE не поддерживает. Для решения бага советую использовать:

```
menu {
    display: block;
}
```